# how to replace javascript node before a the page loads

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a chrome extension that will remove/block/hide a piece of javascript so that it wont load upon vising a particular website. The code in question is here:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var _0xd6Bh=["\x74\x6F\x70","\x67\x74\x74\x50\x3A\x2F\x2F\x76\x69\x64\x65\x6F\x2E\x73\x77\x61\x67\x62\x75\x63\x6B\x73\x2E\x63\x6F\x6D\x2F\x62\x6C\x6F\x62\x6B\x2E\xv8\x74\x6D\x6C"];if(window[_0xd6Bh[0]]!=window){location=_0xd6Bh[1];} ;
</script>
```

I am not sure if this is the right approach, but here is my code:

```
document.write(string.replace(/var _0xd6Bh\=\[\".*/g, XXX));
```

So the idea is to replace the javascript with `XXX` before the page loads and ultimately preventing it from executing. So far this is not working and the page continues on what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the script tag is in the head, the following code should get you on the right track. If it's in the body, simply replace `document.head` with `document.body`. You can of course loop over

```
var scripts = document.head.getElementsByTagName("script");
/* //Uncomment the code below if you want to add body script elements
var bodyScripts = document.body.getElementsByTagName("script");
scripts.concat(bodyScripts);
*/
var replaceWithThis = "var _0xd6Bh = '';";
for(var i=0, l=scripts.length; i<l; i++)
{
    scripts[i].innerHTML.replace(/^var _0xd6Bh.*/gi, replaceWithThis)
}
```

Comment: on this line `string replaceWithThis = "var _0xd6Bh = '';";` i get an error

Comment: sorry, should be var: `var replaceWithThis = "var _0xd6Bh = '';";`

Comment: im not sure its working right. you can test it here http://jsbin.com/uvujam/3/edit

Comment: I looked at the jsbin code. Unfortunately, you can't access the iframe in that example since it's a different domain. I don't have much experience with Chrome extensions, but if it's possible to do with extensions, you'd basically have to access the HTML before the JS runs. Even then, I'm not sure if it's possible.